# How to tell if local dynamodb is up?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to write a script that will check if a local dynamodb instance is running, if it is, do nothing. If not, start one with:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

Solution that works in node.js would be best. I am using the AWS SDK for node.

Answer (score 5):

Since [DynamoDB Local](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) starts listening on a local port, you could check and see if there is a daemon listening on that port with [nc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) as follows:

```
 nc -z localhost 8000
```

It returns 0/success if something is listening or 1 if nothing is listening.

Answer (score 0):

The following shell script checks if DynamoDB Local is running, and if not, it starts it.

```
#!/bin/sh

check_process() {
  echo "$ts: checking $1"
  [ "$1" = "" ]  && return 0
  [ `pgrep -f $1` ] && return 1 || return 0
}

echo "Checking if DynamoDB is already running..." check_process "dynamodb"
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "DynamoDB is not running, starting..." && `java -Djava.library.path=. -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar` &
```

Answer (score -6):

`DynamoDB` is NoSQL database. It is not a database server which requires server start/stop. You can check the tables present in the database or status of a specific table. e,g. CREATING/UPDATING/DELETING/ACTIVE. You can use tables only if table status is **ACTIVE**.